# Create index in Mongoose for array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have two models setup:

## ShopsModel

```
var ShopsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var ShopsModel = mongoose.model("Shops", ShopsSchema);
```

## FieldGroupsModel

```
var FieldGroupsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  fields: [{
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    handle: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }],
  shop: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Shops"
  }
});

var FieldGroupsModel = mongoose.model("FieldGroups", FieldGroupsSchema)
```

Each FieldGroups instance has a ShopsModel associated with it.

I need to create an index for the FieldGroupsModel `fields[i].handle` value, this index needs two rules; it needs to be unique to each FieldGroupsModel instance, so this data would be invalid:

```
{
  title: "Some field group title here",
  fields: [
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1"
    },
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1" // Error: `some-label-1` already exists as a value of `fields[i].handle`.
    }
  ],
  shop: {
    "$oid": "1"
  }
}
```

The second rule is that the first rule should only be in place for FieldGroupsModel instances which share the same `shop` value. So this data would be invalid:

```
// First bit of data
{
  title: "Some field group title here",
  fields: [
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1"
    }
  ],
  shop: {
    "$oid": "1"
  }
}

// Second bit of data
{
  title: "Another field group title here",
  fields: [
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1" // Error: `some-label-1` already exists as a value of `fields[i].handle` of a document which shares the same `shop` value.
    }
  ],
  shop: {
    "$oid": "1"
  }
}
```

However, this would be valid:

```
// First bit of data
{
  title: "Some field group title here",
  fields: [
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1"
    }
  ],
  shop: {
    "$oid": "1"
  }
}

// Second bit of data
{
  title: "Another field group title here",
  fields: [
    {
      label: "Some label 1"
      handle: "some-label-1" // This is valid because there's no other documents with the same `shop` value with the same `fields[i].handle` value.
    }
  ],
  shop: {
    "$oid": "2"
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to Mongo and Mongoose so any help here would be *greatly* appreciated! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call the `index` method on your Schema object to do that as shown [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes). For your case it would be something like:

```
FieldGroupsSchema.index({"shop": 1, "fields.handle": 1}, {unique: true});
```

Please read the MongoDB documentation about [Compound Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#Indexes-CompoundKeys) for more detail.

Comment: Hey Đức, thanks for the help! I tried this with no luck, duplicates are still being saved.

Comment: Hi @Tom, you have to drop the collection or delete everything exists in the collection before applying the compound index.

Comment: Hey @Đức Nguyễn, yeah I tried this and now it sort of works; it prevents other documents with the same `shop` value containing a duplicate `fields.handle` value which is great and what I want but it still allows duplicate `fields.handle` of the same document; any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Tom, to create index within array element of a document, just add another index to the Schema like this: ensureIndex({"fields.handle":1})

Comment: Anyway, I think you should use $addToSet to add elements to fields array. $addToSet ensure your array is unique. Please refer mongodb $addToSet document for detail: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: Hey @Đức Nguyễn, awesome thanks so much! I now have one more problem :( When I create a new FieldsGroup document, the `fields` value defaults to `[]` which is correct and works fine, then when I try to create another FieldsGroup document, I get a `E11000 duplicate key error index` error, I've learnt that this is because in this scenario the `fields.handle` of each document don't exist and are therefor equal, which isn't unique. I've learnt that I should add `sparse: true` to the index and this will fix this issue but it doesn't. I've dropped all collections/indexes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: My index looks like this: `FieldGroupsSchema.index({"shop": 1, "fields.handle": 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true});`

Comment: Hi @Tom, `spareIndex` permit the insertion of documents that had unique values for the `fields.handle` field or did not include a `fields.handle` field. So please remove the `required: true` attribute in both label and handle property of objects in fields. Like this: `fields: [{label: {type: String},handle: {type: String}}]`

Comment: Hey @Đức Nguyễn, I tried this already and I get the exact same issue - I'm clearing my collections/indexes every time I make changes also. Any more ideas? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144326/discussion-between-tom-and-dc-nguyn).

Comment: Hi @Tom, please try this: `ensureIndex({"shop": 1, "fields.handle": 1},{unique: true, sparse: true, partialFilterExpression: { fields: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } })`.

Comment: Hey again, I ended up using these options `{ unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "fields.handle": { $exists: true } } } )` and it works great. I'm all set now, thanks for all your help! :)