# MongoDb Indexing the ObjectId(_id) for the arrays of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I have an mongodb collection such as products example.

```json
{  
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec5229bda162e089d2ab4ff"),  
    "name" : "Fruit",
    "price" : 2.0,
    "manufacture": [   
        {_id:  ObjectId("5ec5229bda162e089d2ab4ff"), m_name: "M-1" },   
        {_id:  ObjectId("5ec5229bda162e089d2ab4ff"), m_name: "M-2" } 
    ]
}
```

I need to index the `manufacture._id` field since I am querying on this field for several times in my application.

Can I index them or it will be automatically indexed since it also has `_id` in it?.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992823/create-index-in-mongoose-for-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

According to MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index): 'MongoDB creates a unique index on the `_id` field during the creation of a collection.'

So no, your array index will not be created automatically.

To create the index you can specify it in the schema. Something like this (not tested):

```json
_id: {
  type: ObjectId,
  required: true,
  index: true,
  unique:true
}
```

Or also:

```js
YourSchema.index({ "manufacture._id": 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Comment: You are welcome! Also if the answer solve your problem, mark it as accepted is appreciated